# Strangle behavior with WPF MVVM binding on ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, user-interface, data-binding

I have a `System.Windows.ListBox` which is bound to a `ObservableCollection<string>` within the ViewModel, ItemsSource property of the ListBox bound to `LbItems`, constructor containing the following code:

```cs
public DataSetViewModel(DataSetModel _dataSet) {
    LbItems.CollectionChanged += lbFiles_CollectionChanged2;
}
```

**Considering the 2 possible scenario options below....**

Appears as expected (Items set from a `OpenFileDialog` equal Items in ListBox):

```cs
private void lbFiles_CollectionChanged2(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        this.DataSet.InputFileSet = LbItems.ToArray(); 
}
```

Items appear NOT as exepcted(2 of each selected item from the `OpenFileDialog` appear in ListBox):

```cs
private void lbFiles_CollectionChanged2(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Why does this messagebox cause an binding error?");
}
```

.

**Update**

Below is the code for the OpenFileDialog:

```
private void btnLoad__Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.Filter = "CSV File (.csv)|*.csv";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = @"%userprofile%\Documents";
        ofd.Title = "Load CSV data sources";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true) {
            ((DataSetViewModel)this.DataContext).LbItems.Clear(); //bad code - please comment on proper strucutre for MVVM 

            foreach (string str in ofd.FileNames) {
                ((DataSetViewModel)this.DataContext).LbItems.Add(str);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you change the collection in the listbox, are you raising a NotifyPropertyChange event?  You need that for the UI to change.

Comment: There is a button which loads an OpenFileDialog.  The OpenFileDialog modifies the item defined by ItemsSource property of the ListBox, which is an ObservableCollection, so I think you are incorrect.   But that is not the problem.  Things work as expected with the first `lbFiles_CollectionChanged2` method written, but not the 2nd.

Comment: Can you show the OpenFileDialog code? Nothing stands out from these snippets alone but initial guesses are maybe a threading issue or multiple iterations of a non-materialized IEnumerable?

Comment: @JohnBowen I have added the code to the original post.